# Why does this continue to ask for strings?

Tags: java, stack

I am working on a program that is supposed to help students study the presidents. I am using a stack. It is supposed to ask for user input and then it compares the input to the top of the stack. If it is correct it removes the top item. otherwise it asks for the next president. When I get to the end it asks again for the next president even though the stack should be empty.

Here is my main program.

```
package namepresidents;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NamePresidents 
{

    //=========================MAIN=============================================
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       UnboundedStackInterface<String> presidents;
       presidents = new LinkedStack<String>();

       presidents.push("George Washington");
       presidents.push("John Adams");
       presidents.push("Thomas Jefferson");
       presidents.push("James Madison");
       presidents.push("James Monroe");
       presidents.push("John Quincy Adams");
       presidents.push("Andrew Jackson");
       presidents.push("Martin Van Buren");
       presidents.push("James Madison");
       presidents.push("William Henry Harrison");
       presidents.push("John Tyler");
       presidents.push("James K Polk");
       presidents.push("Zachary Taylor");
       presidents.push("James Madison");
       presidents.push("Millard Fillmore");
       presidents.push("Franklin Pierce");
       presidents.push("James Buchanan");
       presidents.push("Abraham Lincoln");
       presidents.push("Andrew Johnson");
       presidents.push("Ulysses S Grant");
       presidents.push("Rutherford B. Hayes");
       presidents.push("James A Garfield");
       presidents.push("Chester A Arthur ");
       presidents.push("Grover Cleveland");
       presidents.push("Benjamin Harrison");
       presidents.push("Grover Cleveland");
       presidents.push("William McKinley");
       presidents.push("William H Taft");
       presidents.push("Woodrow Wilson");
       presidents.push("Warren G Harding");
       presidents.push("Calvin Coolidge");
       presidents.push("Herbert Hoover");
       presidents.push("Franklin D Roosevelt");
       presidents.push("Harry S Truman");
       presidents.push("Dwight D Eisenhower");
       presidents.push("John F Kennedy");
       presidents.push("Lyndon B Johnson");
       presidents.push("Richard M Nixon");
       presidents.push("Gerald R Ford");
       presidents.push("Jimmy Carter");
       presidents.push("Ronald Reagan");
       presidents.push("George Bush");
       presidents.push("Bill Clinton");
       presidents.push("George W Bush");
       presidents.push("Barack Obama");

       UnboundedStackInterface<String> wrongAnswer;
       wrongAnswer = new LinkedStack<String>();


       String menu = "Would you like to study: \n"
                + "1. All the presidents \n"
                + "2. The first half \n"
                + "3. The second half \n"
                + "4. In reverse \n"
                + "0. Exit \n";

        System.out.print(menu);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = in.nextInt();  
        String studentPresidents = in.nextLine();

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:                 
                        do
                        {
                            System.out.print("Enter the next president: ");
                            studentPresidents = in.nextLine();
                            if(studentPresidents.equalsIgnoreCase(presidents.top()))
                            {
                                presidents.pop();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wrongAnswer.push(studentPresidents);
                                System.out.println("That is not correct. Try Again!");
                            }
                        }while(!presidents.isEmpty());

                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("You missed: \n" + wrongAnswer.top());
                                wrongAnswer.pop();
                            }while(!wrongAnswer.isEmpty());

            break;

            case 2: UnboundedStackInterface<String> firstHalf;
                    firstHalf = new LinkedStack<String>();

                    firstHalf.push("George Washington");
                    firstHalf.push("John Adams");
                    firstHalf.push("Thomas Jefferson");
                    firstHalf.push("James Madison");
                    firstHalf.push("James Monroe");
                    firstHalf.push("John Quincy Adams");
                    firstHalf.push("Andrew Jackson");
                    firstHalf.push("Martin Van Buren");
                    firstHalf.push("James Madison");
                    firstHalf.push("William Henry Harrison");
                    firstHalf.push("John Tyler");
                    firstHalf.push("James K Polk");
                    firstHalf.push("Zachary Taylor");
                    firstHalf.push("James Madison");
                    firstHalf.push("Millard Fillmore");
                    firstHalf.push("Franklin Pierce");
                    firstHalf.push("James Buchanan");
                    firstHalf.push("Abraham Lincoln");
                    firstHalf.push("Andrew Johnson");
                    firstHalf.push("Ulysses S Grant");
                    firstHalf.push("Rutherford B Hayes");
                    firstHalf.push("James A Garfield");

                             do
                             {
                                 System.out.print("Enter the next president: ");
                                 studentPresidents = in.nextLine();
                                 if(studentPresidents.equalsIgnoreCase(firstHalf.top()))
                                 {
                                     firstHalf.pop();
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     wrongAnswer.push(studentPresidents);
                                     System.out.println("That is not correct. Try Again!");
                                 }
                              }while(!presidents.isEmpty());

                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("You missed: \n" + wrongAnswer.top());
                                wrongAnswer.pop();
                            }while(!wrongAnswer.isEmpty());

                 break;

            case 3: UnboundedStackInterface<String> lastHalf;
                    lastHalf = new LinkedStack<String>(); 

                    lastHalf.push("Chester A Arthur");
                    lastHalf.push("Grover Cleveland");
                    lastHalf.push("Benjamin Harrison");
                    lastHalf.push("Grover Cleveland");
                    lastHalf.push("William McKinley");
                    lastHalf.push("William H Taft");
                    lastHalf.push("Woodrow Wilson");
                    lastHalf.push("Warren G Harding");
                    lastHalf.push("Calvin Coolidge");
                    lastHalf.push("Herbert Hoover");
                    lastHalf.push("Franklin D Roosevelt");
                    lastHalf.push("Harry S Truman");
                    lastHalf.push("Dwight D Eisenhower");
                    lastHalf.push("John F Kennedy");
                    lastHalf.push("Lyndon B Johnson");
                    lastHalf.push("Richard M Nixon");
                    lastHalf.push("Gerald R Ford");
                    lastHalf.push("Jimmy Carter");
                    lastHalf.push("Ronald Reagan");
                    lastHalf.push("George Bush");
                    lastHalf.push("Bill Clinton");
                    lastHalf.push("George W Bush");
                    lastHalf.push("Barack Obama");

                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("Enter the next president: ");
                                studentPresidents = in.nextLine();
                                if(studentPresidents.equalsIgnoreCase(lastHalf.top()))
                                {
                                    lastHalf.pop();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    wrongAnswer.push(studentPresidents);
                                    System.out.println("That is not correct. Try Again!");
                                }
                            } while(!presidents.isEmpty());

                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("You missed: \n" + wrongAnswer.top());
                                wrongAnswer.pop();
                            }while(!wrongAnswer.isEmpty());

                            break;


            case 4: UnboundedStackInterface<String> reversePres;
                     reversePres = new LinkedStack<String>();

                     do
                     {
                        reversePres.push(presidents.top());
                        presidents.pop();
                     }while(!presidents.isEmpty());

                     do
                     {
                         System.out.print("Enter the next president: ");
                                studentPresidents = in.nextLine();
                                if(studentPresidents.equalsIgnoreCase(reversePres.top()))
                                {
                                    reversePres.pop();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    wrongAnswer.push(studentPresidents);
                                    System.out.println("That is not correct. Try Again!");
                                }
                      }while(!reversePres.isEmpty());

                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("You missed: \n" + wrongAnswer.top());
                                wrongAnswer.pop();
                            }while(!wrongAnswer.isEmpty());

                      break;

            case 0: System.out.println("Exit!");
                    break;

            default: break;
        }   
    }

}
```

Here is my LinkedStack class

```
package namepresidents;

public class LinkedStack<T> implements
        UnboundedStackInterface<T>
{
    protected LLNode<T> top;

    //=================================constructor==============================
    public LinkedStack()
    {
        top = null;
    }

    //===================================push===================================
    public void push(T element)
    {
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<>(element);
        newNode.setLink(top);
        top = newNode;
    }

    //====================================pop===================================
    public void pop()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            top = top.getLink();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Pop"
            + "Attempted on empty stack.");
        }
    }

    //=====================================top==================================
    public T top()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            return top.getInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StackUnderflowException("top"
            + "Attempted on empty stack.");
        }
    }

    //======================================isEmpty=============================
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my LLNODE class

```
package namepresidents;

public class LLNode<T> 
{
    private T info;
    private LLNode<T> link;

    public LLNode(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
        link = null;
    }

    public void setInfo(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public T getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setLink(LLNode<T> link)
    {
        this.link = link;

    }

    public LLNode<T> getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }


}
```

Comment: Which option are you typing in?

Comment: FYI, I tried Option 1 and your code worked fine.  (I didn't use `UnboundedStackInterface` because it's not part of Java and I don't know what it is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in options 2 and 3. Look at this reduced loop code:

```
do
{
    if(studentPresidents.equalsIgnoreCase(firstHalf.top()))
    {
        firstHalf.pop(); // pops firstHalf
    }
}while(!presidents.isEmpty()); // tests presidents
```

This is why copy and paste programming is bad. It is prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

For cases 2 and 3 your while() test should be checking the half lists, rather than presidents list.